# The first tensorflow training step takes longer than any other

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection-api

While working on my tensorflow (v.1.14) object detection api project i noticed that the first epoch takes the longest to train.

Since i am working on an active learning pipeline and i have a "cold start" with only one training image and a training time constraint, it is crucial to fix this issue.

Sometimes it takes a factor of 5 more time to train the first epoch.
I have read about people running into similar issues but there was no solute yet.

Comment: Which tensorflow version is this?

Comment: Version 1.14 - i added it to the question